# Consulta LINQ TO XML com Elemento opcional

Tags: c#, xml, query, linq

Olá pessoal estou com uma dúvida para exibir os dados de um arquivo **XML** através de uma consulta **LINQ** , o problema e que estou tentado consultar os dados da pessoa mas o preenchimento obrigatório e nome e CPF ou CNPJ portanto em alguns casos não existem os registro de **`Endereço`** e **`Contato`** então a exceção **NullReferenceException** e lançada como posso resolver isso ?

**Estrutura do Arquivo xml**

```
<!--<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>-->
<Lista>
  <Pessoa>
    <CpfCnpj></CpfCnpj>  <!-- Preenchimento Obrigatorio --> 
    <Nome></Nome>         <!-- Preenchimento Obrigatório --> 
    <Endereco>
      <Endereco></Endereco>
      <Numero></Numero>
      <Complemento>;</Complemento>
      <Bairro></Bairro>
      <Cidade></Cidade>
      <Uf></Uf>
      <Cep></Cep>
    </Endereco>
    <Contato>
      <Telefone></Telefone>
      <Email></Email>
    </Contato>
  </Pessoa>
</Lista>
```

**Consulta LINQ TO XML**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Carrega Aquivo
            XDocument xmldoc = XDocument.Load("Database.xml");

            var ConsutarPessoas  = from p in xmldoc.Descendants("Pessoa")
                select new
                    {
                        CpfCnpj     = p.Element("CpfCnpj").Value,
                        Nome        = p.Element("Nome").Value,
                        Endereco    = p.Element("Endereco").Element("Endereco").Value,
                        Numero      = p.Element("Endereco").Element("Numero").Value,
                        Complemento = p.Element("Endereco").Element("Complemento").Value,
                        Bairro      = p.Element("Endereco").Element("Bairro").Value,
                        Cidade      = p.Element("Endereco").Element("Cidade").Value,
                        Uf          = p.Element("Endereco").Element("Endereco").Value,
                        Cep         = p.Element("Endereco").Element("Uf").Value,
                        Telefone    = p.Element("Contato").Element("Telefone").Value,
                        Email       = p.Element("Contato").Element("Email").Value,
                    };
            //Exibir dados das pessoas 
            foreach (var PessoaRerefenciada in ConsutarPessoas)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(PessoaRerefenciada.CpfCnpj);
                Console.WriteLine(PessoaRerefenciada.Nome);
                Console.WriteLine(PessoaRerefenciada.Endereco);
                Console.WriteLine(PessoaRerefenciada.Complemento);
                Console.WriteLine(PessoaRerefenciada.Numero);
                Console.WriteLine(PessoaRerefenciada.Bairro);
                Console.WriteLine(PessoaRerefenciada.Cidade);
                Console.WriteLine(PessoaRerefenciada.Cep);
                Console.WriteLine(PessoaRerefenciada.Telefone);
                Console.WriteLine(PessoaRerefenciada.Email);
                Console.WriteLine("----------------------");
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

**Obs** : Sei que posso construir uma estrutura melhor mas neste caso não posso realizar nenhuma modificação .

Comment: Veja se o elemento p.Element("Endereco") tem valor antes de de acessar seu "Value" .. Tipo p.Element("Endereco") != null ?  p.Element("Endereco").Element("Cidade") != null ? p.Element("Endereco").Element("Cidade").Value : "" : "";

Comment: Testa se é null antes.  Endereco = p.Element("Endereco").Element("Endereco").Value ==  null ? "" : p.Element("Endereco").Element("Endereco").Value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Um bloco `try ... catch` resolve bem isso, não?

```
try 
{
    var ConsutarPessoas  = from p in xmldoc.Descendants("Pessoa")
            select new
                {
                    CpfCnpj     = p.Element("CpfCnpj").Value,
                    Nome        = p.Element("Nome").Value,
                    Endereco    = p.Element("Endereco").Element("Endereco").Value,
                    Numero      = p.Element("Endereco").Element("Numero").Value,
                    Complemento = p.Element("Endereco").Element("Complemento").Value,
                    Bairro      = p.Element("Endereco").Element("Bairro").Value,
                    Cidade      = p.Element("Endereco").Element("Cidade").Value,
                    Uf          = p.Element("Endereco").Element("Endereco").Value,
                    Cep         = p.Element("Endereco").Element("Uf").Value,
                    Telefone    = p.Element("Contato").Element("Telefone").Value,
                    Email       = p.Element("Contato").Element("Email").Value,
                };
} catch (Exception e) { /* Trate os problemas aqui */ }
```

Ou ainda, iterar de uma forma que o `try ... catch` fique dentro do bloco:

```
foreach (var p in xmldoc.Descendants("Pessoa"))
{
    try { /* Coloque a atribuição aqui */ }
    catch { /* Trate problemas de referência nula aqui */ }
}
```